# jqxdropdownlist load from other jqxdropdownlist

Tags: jquery, jqwidget

i have 2 jqxDropDownList that items is equls.

i write this code but this code send 2 request(same as) to server.

how can copy items from first jqxDropDownList to second jqxDropDownList?

```
var source = {
         datatype: "json",
         datafields: [{
             name: 'organizationName'
         }, {
             name: 'id'
         }],
         id: 'id',
         url: "getOrganizationName",
         async: true
     };
     var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
    //people
     $("#slc_organizationName_people").jqxDropDownList({
         source: dataAdapter,
         displayMember: "organizationName",
         valueMember: "id"
     });
    //address
     $("#slc_organizationName_address").jqxDropDownList({
         source: dataAdapter,
         displayMember: "organizationName",
         valueMember: "id"
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an approach like below:

```
var source = {
     datatype: "json",
     datafields: [{
         name: 'organizationName'
     }, {
         name: 'id'
     }],
     id: 'id',
     url: "getOrganizationName",
     async: true
 };
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source,{
    loadComplete: function()
    {
     //address
        var source2 = {
             datatype: "array",
             datafields: [{
                 name: 'organizationName'
             }, {
                 name: 'id'
             }],
             id: 'id',
           localdata: dataAdapter.records
         };
         var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source2);
         $("#slc_organizationName_address").jqxDropDownList({
             source: adapter ,
             displayMember: "organizationName",
             valueMember: "id"
         });
    } 
});
//people
 $("#slc_organizationName_people").jqxDropDownList({
     source: dataAdapter,
     displayMember: "organizationName",
     valueMember: "id"
 });
```

Comment: what is `source2`?  var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source2);  say error is undefined

Comment: change  var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source2); to  var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source); this worked but still send 2 request

Comment: oh oh .must `var souce2 =` rename to `source2`. this worked and send only 1 request to server.thank you very much